# Auto-populated field in a Sequelize Model?

Tags: mysql, node.js, database, model, sequelize.js

I'm creating a Model for a 'users' table in MySQL. Ideally I'd like to have a 'firstName' and 'lastName' field and a 'fullName' that would be the addition of the other 2.
Is it possible to have that programatically in the Model or do I have to take care of that at INSERT time ?

```js
const User = sequelize.define("users", {
  id: {
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    autoIncrement: true,
    allowNull: false,
    primaryKey: true,
  },
  firstName: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING(50),
    allowNull: false,
  },
  lastName: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING(50),
    allowNull: false,
  },
  fullName: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING(50),
    allowNull: false,
    // something that makes 'firstName' + ' ' + 'lastName' ❤️

  },
  email: {
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER(30),
    allowNull: false,
  },
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Virtual Colums* are what you are looking for.

> "Virtual" columns are columns that do not get saved in your database - they are calculated on the fly based on the values of other columns. They are helpful for saving space if there are values we want to use on our instances that can be easily calculated.

```
    const User = sequelize.define("users", {
      id: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        autoIncrement: true,
        allowNull: false,
        primaryKey: true,
      },
      firstName: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING(50),
        allowNull: false,
      },
      lastName: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING(50),
        allowNull: false,
      },
       fullName: {
         type: DataTypes.VIRTUAL,
         get() {
               return `${this.firstName} ${this.lastName}`;
         }
      },
      email: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER(30),
        allowNull: false,
      },
    });
```

For more infromation see [virtual fields.](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/getters-setters-virtuals.html#virtual-fields)